# Is there a way I can have internal emails from Salesforce sent via a different domain name?

Tags: email, reporting, dashboard, deliverability

I am having quite a major issue in convincing the IT dept to accept that emails from Salesforce, sent from users of Salesforce with their email addresses, are not phishing attempts.

I have sent them to all of the literature from Salesforce but still I cannot get Dashboards, Reports, Workflow emails etc through the firewalls.

If these came from reports@salesforce.com or similar... Or is there something else I can do?

Comment: The only solution to this is routing an email through another SMTP service (aka [relay](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=email_relay.htm&type=5)). Have you tried asking your IT dept if you could have Salesforce send through their email server?

Comment: @identigral Internal IT would only relay internally.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting up your org wide emails and verifying them?

I would also do a deliver-ability test and give your IT department the email IP ranges needed by all the salesforce email servers.

Our IT was a bit reluctant so I got them on a call with salesforce support to explain why this was needed and the salesforce support also convinced them to go ahead and setup DKIM keys after the call to avoid landing in customers junk / spam folders.

Comment: I have. They are unwilling to white list any IP address